# How to hide Navigation Bar back button title from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whenever my app receives a push notification with custom payload I'd like to push the app to a `UIViewController`, I was able to do it but I cannot remove the title from the Back button of the `UINavigationBar` from the `AppDelegate`.

What I tried was:

```
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor mainBlue]];
    self.window.rootViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.window.rootViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
```

The last line is where I set the title of the back button to `nil` but it doesn not work, when the `UIViewController` becomes visible I can still se the title. The code works if I use it on the `UIViewController` before that one but not on the `AppDelegate`. Does anyone have a solution? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This will hide back button title from all navigation items. You should change the offset value based on your title length.

Comment: Thanks! :) just wondering, do you know why setting the title doesn't work in the AppDelegate?

Comment: Welcome:), when you use `appearance` for any control (in our case: `UIBarButtonItem`) it will set it to update for the entire app. In your case, its pointing to current navigation bar and its back button item. You may have multiple `UINavigationController` in your app.